# Product space definition

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, solution-verification, definition, product-space

Herebelow, all passages in *Billingsley* $(1995)$ to get to definition of product spaces:

> The standard construction of the general process involves product spaces. Let $T$ be an arbitrary index set and $R^T$ be the collection of all real functions on $T$.
>  If $T=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, [...] $R^T$ can be identified with $k$-dimensional Euclidean space $R^k$. [...] Whatever the set $T$ may be, an element of $R^T$ will be denoted $x$.

So far so good, I guess. As far as I understand, $R^T$ is hust the collection of all the possible maps from $T$ to $R^1$ and, if $T=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, $R^T=R^k$. Going on:

> Just as $R^k$ can be regarded as the cartesian product of $k$ copies of the real line, $R^T$ can be regarded as a product space - a product of copies of the real line, one copy for each $t$ in $T$

**First doubt**: as to the immediately-above statement, in plain language (sorry, I am not very comfortable with such concepts by now), what does it mean that $$\text{"}R^k\text{ can be regarded as the cartesian product of }k \text{ copies of the real line"}$$?
**My interpretation**: start with $T=\{1,2\ldots,k\}$; corresponding to each $t\in T$, $x_t$ can possibly take every value in the real line $R^1$, hence I would define $R^k$ as follows:
$$R^k=\{(x_{1}^{\alpha},...,x_{k}^{\alpha})\hspace{0.3cm}|\hspace{0.3cm}x_{\eta}^{\alpha}\in R^1,\text{ with }\eta\in\{1,\ldots,k\} \text{ and }\alpha\in R^1\}$$
Rearranging a bit, I would say that $R^k$ is made up of the cartesian products of all the possible combinations of values of $x_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,k$), with $x_i$ possibly taking values on all the real line $R^1$.
Is that correct? Is there anything wrong in my reasoning?
**Second doubt**: what does it mean that $$\text{"}R^T\text{ can be regarded as a product space - a product of copies of the real line, one copy for each }t \text{ in }T\text{"}$$?
**My intepretation**: I would interpret this statement just as a generalization of the above statement. While in the above statement, starting point is $T=\{1,\ldots,k\}$, now $T$ is generic.
Is that correct? Is there anything wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: $R^T$ can better be looked at as the set of all possible maps $T\to R$. If you define it as the set of maps $T\to R^1$ then you introduce a new question: what is $R^1$?

Comment: Following your "first doubt", I would suggest a different interpration. Take what he said literally: use several different **copies** of the real line. The real line, of course, is just a complete ordered field. All complete ordered fields, of course, are isomorphic to the real line. So now you can use this freedom to imagine several different **complete ordered fields**, where "different" is meant literally, they are different sets with different operations, despite them all being isomorphic to each other. People often use this kind of freedom when they say "take several copies of BLAH".

Comment: @drhab I don't mean to define it as $T\mapsto R^1$; I'm just focusing on each $t\in T$ and stating that $x_t:t\mapsto R^1$

Comment: @LeeMosher could you please suggest a good topology book for almost-beginners? I am very interested in your explanation and I would like a lot to get it well. For example, a "strange" fact to me is that two isomorphic sets are not necessarily equipped with the same operations. Additionally, my idea of.."see $R^k$ as the cartesian products of all the possible combinations of values of $x_i (i=1,\ldots,k)$, with $x_i$ possibly taking values on all the real line $R^1$" is wrong or could be seen at least as an almost good interpretation?

Comment: Your interpretation is just as good, as is the interpretation of @HennoBrandsma. The common theme here is the idea of *isomorphism* between two mathematical objects with the same structure, e.g. between two vector spaces of dimension $n$; or between two complete ordered fields.

Comment: Thank you a lot. So, why  two isomorphic sets are not necessarily equipped with the same operations? @LeeMosher

Comment: That's an interesting question in set theory, but it is somewhat beyond the scope of your current question, and the comment thread of this question is not a good place for this discussion. If you could formulate a good mathematical question along these lines, you could post it as a new question, but perhaps before doing that you should ask yourself what **you** mean by the word "same".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^T$ is just the set of *functions* $f: T \to R$; this also means that for each $t \in T$ we have a point $f(t) \in R$. An $n$ tuple $(x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_n) \in R^n$ is identified with $f$ defined on the finite set $T=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with $f(i)=x_i$. This is functionally the same thing: $n$ independently chosen values in order, just like the $n$-tuple we traditionally know as a product. In order to generalise this we can just extend the domain from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to *any* set at all. FOr $T=\Bbb N$ we get sequence spaces, and the function $f:\Bbb N \to R$ chooses countably many independent values in $R$ (hence the term "a product of $\Bbb N$ many copies of $R$..).

So the essence of the "product idea" is choosing independent values in each coordinate. This we see in finite $n$-tuples as well as in a functions. A product then becomes a set of functions, which is a useful concept also in analysis.

Comment: Pardon, I am still confused.  So, my interpretation is wrong if I properly understand, isn't it? That is, "see $R^k$ as the cartesian products of all the possible combinations of values of $x_i (i=1,\ldots,k)$, with $x_i$ possibly taking values on all the real line $R_1$.". I see a permutations spirit in the definition since it is said to take "$k$ **copies** of the real line $R^1$". So, if I am wrong, what does it exactly mean to "take $k$ **copies** of the real line $R^1$"?
@HennoBrandsma

Comment: @Strictly_increasing that’s because we choose independently. If we choose $x_1=1$, that has no effect on what $x_2$ can be in a tuple. So the different coordinates have separate “copies” of $R$, or so it could be presented. What would be your issue with the word “copy”?

Comment: OK, great, now it seems clearer. Additionally, in general you do confirm that definition of $R^T$ above is just a generalization of definition above of $R^k$ (or, equivalently, that definition of $R^k$ is just a special case of definition of $R^T$), don't you? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Yes, that's the whole point.  Both $R^k$ and $R^T$ are sets of functions; only the domains of the functions differ, the range is just $R$. There is just one $R$ involved, the copies methaphore is just a "manner of speaking".

Comment: Pardon, just a last question, a bit OT but consistent with my question "area": since I am not very comfortable with topology by now, could you please suggest some good Topology book to start with (almost-beginner level)? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Munkres Topology  seems to be popular. I haven’t taught from it myself but it does start at the basics.